# how to make summary using python groupby. able to find sum and count unable to do > and <

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

my input is

```
Circle  |Link   |Utilization
-----------------------------
Delhi   del51-del63 15.11
Delhi   del51-del63 17
Delhi   del51-del63 34.82285714
Delhi   del51-del63 34.82285714
Mumbai  mum1012-mum233  42
Mumbai  mum412-mum2121  42.15
Mumbai  mum1012-mum245  58.82285714
Mumbai  mum10-mum2121   77.52
Delhi   del51-del61 81
Delhi   del51-del62 88
Mumbai  mum1012-mum2121 95
```

Please help as I am unable to make summary using groupby.

my out put would be summary as below

```
Circle  |Link_count |<50    |>=50 & <80 |>=80
---------------------------------------
Delhi   6   4   0   2
-------------------------
Mumbai  5   2   2   1
--------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupby`, using `pd.cut` to form the groups, to get the group sizes. `right=False` gets the closure you want for your groupings. Then you can add the sum after the `groupby`. You can either simply assign, or if the location is important use `insert`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.cut(df['Utilization'], [-np.inf, 50, 80, np.inf], right=False,
           labels=['<50', '>=50 & <80', '>=80'])

output = df.groupby(['Circle', s]).size().unstack(-1).rename_axis(columns=None)
output.insert(0, 'Link_count', output.sum(axis=1))
```

---

```
print(output)

        Link_count  <50  >=50 & <80  >=80
Circle                                   
Delhi            6    4           0     2
Mumbai           5    2           2     1
```

Comment: getting this error after output syntax

Comment: @SudarshanWaman what error?

Comment: TypeError: 'fill_value=Link_count' is not present in this Categorical's categories